# Which View for a "fancy" scroller?

Tags: android, spinner, scrollview, scroller

I'm developing an app that require the selection of one element (out of three) from the user.

Right now I've tried to developed a Spinner, and then a RadioGroup, they were both working but I find them not really catching.
The spinner is too simple, but easy to see. In the other hand the RadioGroup is more fancy (with some background customization), but not yet nice as I would.

I would like to implement something like a ScrollView, but with that nice "bumping" effect, the selection in the middle and the shadow on top and bottom.

A sample image:

[image]

The Libra app has this kind View for the adding of your weight:

[image]

Is the Scroller what I'm looking for? Any example or tutorial?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider ?

Comment: I think this Many Links Help you, [http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/) [https://github.com/casidiablo/date-slider](https://github.com/casidiablo/date-slider) [https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider](https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [AndroidWheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) is what you are looking for

Comment: Seems nice. It's a shame that there's no native View for this, btw. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Actually, native `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` look exactly like you want starting from Android 4.0 I think there is a backport for previous android versions.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not implementing date or time, so I should customize them. But that's also an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default View would do what you're asking for. `Gallery` does something similar but is deprecated.

Scroller isn't a View but a utility class to help View's implement Scrolling.

There are of course, libraries available to help you.